# incorrectly invoked stream listeners on rabbitmq message consumer with spring-cloud-stream

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have a project that is `spring-cloud-starter-parent:Hoxton.SR9`.
the main objective here is messaging, thus there are message (kafka/rabbit) producers and consumers declared:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default-binder: kafka
      contentType: application/*+avro
      bindings:
        loanContractWaitingForActivationInput:
          binder: rabbit
          destination: icebank
          group: LH_LoanEventKeeper_testing2
          contentType: application/json
        loanContractComponentsChangedInput:
          binder: rabbit
          destination: icebank
          group: LH_LoanEventKeeper_testing2
          contentType: application/json
        loanOfferPresentedInput:
          binder: rabbit
          destination: icebank
          group: LH_LoanEventKeeper_testing2
          contentType: application/json
        postingEntryRequestInput:
          destination: PAY_PaymentServices_PostingEntryRequest
          group: LH_LoanEventKeeper
          contentType: application/*+avro
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 1
            autoCommitOnError: true
            headerMode: embeddedHeaders

      kafka:
        bindings:
          postingEntryRequestInput:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOnError: true
        binder:
          configuration:
            security:
              protocol: ${KAFKA_SECURITY_PROTOCOL:SSL}
            ssl:
              truststore:
                location: path
                password: ****
                type: JKS

      rabbit:
        binder:
          useSSL: ${AMQP_SSL_ENABLED:true}
        bindings:
          loanContractWaitingForActivationInput:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: loans.contracts.waitingForActivation
              exchange-auto-delete: false
          loanContractComponentsChangedInput:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: loans.contracts.components
              exchange-auto-delete: false
          loanOfferPresentedInput:
            consumer:
              bindingRoutingKey: loans.offers.presented
              exchange-auto-delete: false
```

alongside with typed `@StreamListener`s provided:

```
    @StreamListener(target = MultiInputChannelsRabbit.LOAN_CONTRACT_WAITING_FOR_ACTIVATION_INPUT)
    void receiveLoanContractWaitingForActivation(@Payload LoanContractWaitingForActivationRabbit message, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
        messageBusConsumerService.receive(message, headers);
    }

    @StreamListener(target = MultiInputChannelsRabbit.LOAN_CONTRACT_COMPONENTS_CHANGED_INPUT)
    void receiveLoanContractComponentsChanged(@Payload LoanContractComponentsChangedRabbit message, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
        messageBusConsumerService.receive(message, headers);
    }

    @StreamListener(target = MultiInputChannelsRabbit.LOAN_OFFER_PRESENTED_INPUT)
    void receiveLoanOfferPresented(@Payload LoanOfferPresentedRabbit message, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
        messageBusConsumerService.receive(message, headers);
    }

    @StreamListener(target = MultiInputChannelsKafka.POSTING_ENTRY_REQUEST_INPUT)
    void receivePostingEntryRequest(@Payload PostingEntryRequest message, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
        messageBusConsumerService.receive(message, headers);
    }
```

with rabbitmq exchange configured:
[image]

with that being said, problem is that with this configuration program receives the message with specific routing key on all 4 streamListener consumer endpoints. in turn. so first
`receiveLoanContractWaitingForActivation(..)` is invoked with the message type not matching the declared payload as the first parameter goes, after that `receiveLoanContractComponentsChanged(..)` same story as with the first, then the correct one (according to the message's routing key: `receiveLoanOfferPresented(..)`), message gets processed correctly as the correct listener was invoked then, the last, incorrect one `receivePostingEntryRequest(..)` ending up the same as first and second.

so basically it seems like I'm failing to bind `@StreamListener` to the proper queue in the exchange which I thought will be specified by the routing key.

Can you, please, point out missing/incorrect piece of configuration in here?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same destination/group for all 3 bindings; you need a separate queue for each.

The routing key is simply a binding between the queue and the exchange; with your current setup you have a single queue with three bindings.

Change the groups so they are unique.

Comment: yeah that fixes that. unfortunatelly `group` means different thing for rabbit and kafka consumers as for kafka you can have the same ones...

Comment: Even with Kafka, it's best to use a different group - otherwise a rebalance on one will cause an unnecessary rebalance on the others.